# Style label font size

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-spring-boot

I'm trying to make H3 label, at this point I use built-in Vaadin theme - ValoTheme.This is how i create new label:

```
Label label = new Label();
label.setCaption("myLabel");
label.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H3);
```

But for some reason, label keeps unstyled. 
The question is - how i could stylish Label without using CSS?

Thanks

P.S UI class has been annotated with @Theme(ValoTheme.THEME_NAME)

**Update:** Making primary button with ValoTheme styling as described above, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Try with addStyleName instead of setStyleName

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took for a while to investigate and found solution that fits me best. The issue has been related to 'label.setCaption(caption);' method, which set components caption, but it denied object customizations.

Thanks to @André Schild for suggestion. So i tested these two small solutions and they worked fine:

```
Label label = new Label(caption);
label.setStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H3);
```

and

```
Label label = new Label(caption);
label.addStyleName(ValoTheme.LABEL_H3);
```

I hope it helps someone

Comment: As you noticed, a Label component has both a "value" and a "caption". The caption is something the containing layout will render, whereas the value is really what the style name affects. You can think of Label like a read-only TextField – both have a caption, and some text under the caption.